# GNU make rule for multiple input files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a GNU make variable with multiple audio files in it:

`FILEWAV += $(wildcard $(DIRIN)/*.wav)`

I need to transform wavs into f32 files using SoX:

`sox -channels 1 --rate 48000 $(FILEWAV) --type raw $(FILEWAV:.wav=.f32)`

How would I write a makefile target to transform all files one by one?

Comment: Have you read through the Make documentation? The section on [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) might be of particular interest.

Comment: If you show us the makefile you tried to write and provide some error messages or explain how it doesn't work, we can explain the error in your makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
%.f32: %.wav
    sox --channels 1 --encoding signed-integer --rate 48000 $< --type raw $@


run: $(MY_FILES_F32) $(MY_OTHER_FILES_F32)
```